# How to redirect stderr to null in cmd.exe

Tags: redirect, stderr, cmd

I have an application that logs a lot of noise to stderr and REALLY slows down the execution of the application. I would like to redirect that output to null. Is this possible with cmd.exe?

Comment: like this: command 2> nul

Comment: See also on superuser: [> /dev/null for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/134214)

Comment: I you want to totally silence a command (stdout and stderr) do `@command > nul 2>&1`

Comment: [su] would be a better place to ask questions about how to use your computer.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
Your DOS command 2> nul
```

Read page *[Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))*. Besides the "2>" construct mentioned by Tanuki Software, it lists some other useful combinations.

Comment: However following will do almost the opposite of what some may expect `copy foo.txt con >> bar 2>nul`. bar will contain the text *one file(s) copied* and the console will containt the content of *foo.txt*.

Comment: Note that this method outputs a blank line, which might cause problems for some scripts. I am still trying to find a way to suppress that.

Comment: @Mawg I don't think it does. It's probably something specific to your usage scenario. Case in point: `@for /L %C in (1,1,10) do @type nonexistent 2> nul` does **not** produce ten blank lines.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg That's because `con` is not a synonym for STDOUT; it's a pseudofile associated with actual console, so it's not affected by redirection. Somewhat akin to Linuxish `(cat /proc/version > /dev/tty) > bar`: the outer redirect won't affect the inner one.

Comment: If I give `non exitsant command` or soem random `umjumflunge` and redirect to `nul`, I still get a blank lien at the DOD prompt

Comment: @Mawg That's just the interactive cmd behavior which won't affect scripting. It simply adds a blank line after each interactive command it executes, I/O redirection or not. Try: http://pastebin.com/JMeA6Mti

Comment: I think there is a problem in the accepted answer. It should be 2>&1> nul You are only redirecting stderr; not stdout, as in `gswin64c --help 2>&1> nul`

Comment: @SamHabiel Not really. The question is about `stderr`.

Comment: Referenced page is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: DOS commands aren't supported any more are they?  A win console command, yes.

Comment: I always forget it's one `l` then end up creating a file called `null` and get unreasonably pissed off