# What is the DOS equivalent of 1>/dev/null?

Tags: dos, dev-null

I want to suppress the output of my script running under DOS, similar to the following under a *nix environment:

```
 $ command 1>/dev/null
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe which works better for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect stderr to null in cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4507312/608639)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should be `>NUL` on both DOS and Windows console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
command >nul: 2>nul:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using *> NUL*

```
copy mfc42d.dll $windir\system32 > nul
regsvr32 $windir\system32\mfc42d.dll /s > nul
```