# MATLAB System Command "Press Enter to Exit"

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd, enter

I am trying to write a MATLAB script that would call and run an external program and then proceed with other MATLAB commands.

```
tic                       %Start stopwatch
system('MyProgram.exe')   %Call and run my program
toc                       %End stopwatch
```

However, this program "MyProgram.exe" requires me to "Press Enter to Exit." How to make my MATLAB script pass "Enter" to proceed? Like How to pass "Enter" as an input of my program at the end of execution? Or how to do this in general ?

Comment: It could be as simple as passing the second return to the system call : `system('Myprog.exe\n')`

Comment: It will not move to the next line before pressing "Enter". How can MATLAB pass this "Enter" so that the script will continue without user interference ?

Comment: On unix, you can use `system('MyProgram < /dev/null')`. On window, I guess you should be able to use `system('MyProgram.exe < NUL')`, but I'm not able to test it for the moment.

Comment: If your program is on the command line and not GUI-based, you can probably `echo.|MyProgram.exe`

Comment: Thank you very much  m7913d and SomethingDark . Both solutions work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On **UNIX**, you can use

```
system('MyProgram < /dev/null').
```

as suggested in the [Matlab documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html):

> To disable stdin and type-ahead redirection, include the formatted
>   text `< /dev/null` in the call to the invoked command.

The **Windows** equivalent is (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381973/what-is-the-dos-equivalent-of-1-dev-null)):

```
system('MyProgram.exe < NUL')
```

Answer (score 4):

When a console program needs to take input one time from the user and there is no built-in way to do so (like passing it in as an argument), that input can be `echo`ed and piped to the program. This can also be used to press Enter (again, once) by piping a blank line.

```
echo.|program.exe
```

While traditionally a blank line is generated with `echo` by using the command `echo.`, this can fail if the current directory contains a file called echo that has no extension. To get around this, you can use a `(` instead of a `.`.

```
echo(|program.exe
```

Comment: I seem to recall the Dostips thread discussing alternatives to `echo.` eventually finding a case where `echo/` didn't work.

Comment: Yes, `echo/` fails in case any echoed text begins with `?`; I believe this is the only error case...