# ENTER keypress wihtout touching keyboard in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, keyboard, enter

how its possible to Matlab input work in command window and then press ENTER without touching keyboard..

or any pushbutton function which can do that

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? What are you trying to perform? Maybe a [mcve] may be helpful.

Comment: actually I am running an exe file within my Matlab code, which helps me in calculating some part of my work, this DOS.exe will run and ask question .. like ('what parameter do you want input?') you need to input and then click ENTER,, but I am going to make it GUI where no command window to input and click ENTER,, so input some how I ll code but don't know how to ask Matlab to press ENTER ,, I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755672/matlab-gui-automation/3759730#3759730

Comment: Even more related / possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811768/matlab-system-command-press-enter-to-exit?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB System Command "Press Enter to Exit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811768/matlab-system-command-press-enter-to-exit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **this** generic solution, based on undocumented matlab. It enables to press any button based on a string input (e.g. `'0'`) by searching through a string of possible buttons to press. **Watch out, this will also be pressed outside of the Matlab environment.**

```
function presskey(mykey)
keys={'KEY_FIRST ','KEY_LAST ','KEY_PRESSED ','KEY_RELEASED ','KEY_TYPED ','VK_0 ','VK_1 ','VK_2 ','VK_3 ','VK_4 ','VK_5 ','VK_6 ','VK_7 ','VK_8 ','VK_9 ','VK_A ','VK_ACCEPT ','VK_ADD ','VK_AGAIN ','VK_ALL_CANDIDATES ','VK_ALPHANUMERIC ','VK_ALT ','VK_ALT_GRAPH ','VK_AMPERSAND ','VK_ASTERISK ','VK_AT ','VK_B ','VK_BACK_QUOTE ','VK_BACK_SLASH ','VK_BACK_SPACE ','VK_BRACELEFT ','VK_BRACERIGHT ','VK_C ','VK_CANCEL ','VK_CAPS_LOCK ','VK_CIRCUMFLEX ','VK_CLEAR ','VK_CLOSE_BRACKET ','VK_CODE_INPUT ','VK_COLON ','VK_COMMA ','VK_COMPOSE ','VK_CONTROL ','VK_CONVERT ','VK_COPY ','VK_CUT ','VK_D ','VK_DEAD_ABOVEDOT ','VK_DEAD_ABOVERING ','VK_DEAD_ACUTE ','VK_DEAD_BREVE ','VK_DEAD_CARON ','VK_DEAD_CEDILLA ','VK_DEAD_CIRCUMFLEX ','VK_DEAD_DIAERESIS ','VK_DEAD_DOUBLEACUTE ','VK_DEAD_GRAVE ','VK_DEAD_IOTA ','VK_DEAD_MACRON ','VK_DEAD_OGONEK ','VK_DEAD_SEMIVOICED_SOUND ','VK_DEAD_TILDE ','VK_DEAD_VOICED_SOUND ','VK_DECIMAL ','VK_DELETE ','VK_DIVIDE ','VK_DOLLAR ','VK_DOWN ','VK_E ','VK_END ','VK_ENTER ','VK_EQUALS ','VK_ESCAPE ','VK_EURO_SIGN ','VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK ','VK_F ','VK_F1 ','VK_F10 ','VK_F11 ','VK_F12 ','VK_F13 ','VK_F14 ','VK_F15 ','VK_F16 ','VK_F17 ','VK_F18 ','VK_F19 ','VK_F2 ','VK_F20 ','VK_F21 ','VK_F22 ','VK_F23 ','VK_F24 ','VK_F3 ','VK_F4 ','VK_F5 ','VK_F6 ','VK_F7 ','VK_F8 ','VK_F9 ','VK_FINAL ','VK_FIND ','VK_FULL_WIDTH ','VK_G ','VK_GREATER ','VK_H ','VK_HALF_WIDTH ','VK_HELP ','VK_HIRAGANA ','VK_HOME ','VK_I ','VK_INSERT ','VK_INVERTED_EXCLAMATION_MARK ','VK_J ','VK_JAPANESE_HIRAGANA ','VK_JAPANESE_KATAKANA ','VK_JAPANESE_ROMAN ','VK_K ','VK_KANA ','VK_KANJI ','VK_KATAKANA ','VK_KP_DOWN ','VK_KP_LEFT ','VK_KP_RIGHT ','VK_KP_UP ','VK_L ','VK_LEFT ','VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS ','VK_LESS ','VK_M ','VK_META ','VK_MODECHANGE ','VK_MULTIPLY ','VK_N ','VK_NONCONVERT ','VK_NUM_LOCK ','VK_NUMBER_SIGN ','VK_NUMPAD0 ','VK_NUMPAD1 ','VK_NUMPAD2 ','VK_NUMPAD3 ','VK_NUMPAD4 ','VK_NUMPAD5 ','VK_NUMPAD6 ','VK_NUMPAD7 ','VK_NUMPAD8 ','VK_NUMPAD9 ','VK_O ','VK_OPEN_BRACKET ','VK_P ','VK_PAGE_DOWN ','VK_PAGE_UP ','VK_PASTE ','VK_PAUSE ','VK_PERIOD ','VK_PLUS ','VK_PREVIOUS_CANDIDATE ','VK_PRINTSCREEN ','VK_PROPS ','VK_Q ','VK_QUOTE ','VK_QUOTEDBL ','VK_R ','VK_RIGHT ','VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS ','VK_ROMAN_CHARACTERS ','VK_S ','VK_SCROLL_LOCK ','VK_SEMICOLON ','VK_SEPARATER ','VK_SHIFT ','VK_SLASH ','VK_SPACE ','VK_STOP ','VK_SUBTRACT ','VK_T ','VK_TAB ','VK_U ','VK_UNDEFINED ','VK_UNDERSCORE ','VK_UNDO ','VK_UP ','VK_V ','VK_W ','VK_X ','VK_Y ','VK_Z'};
a=(find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(keys,mykey))));
if ~isempty(a)
    mykey=keys{a(1)};
    robot = java.awt.Robot;
    eval(['robot.keyPress (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.' mykey ')']); 
    eval(['robot.keyRelease (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.' mykey ')']); 
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend