# Capistrano build script using Ant

Tags: ant, capistrano

I have a PHP app I've been deploying with Capistrano for a while now. I'd like to compress js and css locally and perform other cleanup tasks before deploying to the server. I currently use `build_script` to make an Ant call:

```
set :build_script, "ant compress -q"
```

I'm not sure if this is limited to Windows, but my partial output looks like:

```
executing locally: ant compress -q

{$HOME}\AppData\Local\Temp\20120826020126>/*
'/*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

{$HOME}\AppData\Local\Temp\20120826020126>Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
'Licensed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

{$HOME}\AppData\Local\Temp\20120826020126>contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
'contributor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

{$HOME}\AppData\Local\Temp\20120826020126>this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
'this' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

{$HOME}\AppData\Local\Temp\20120826020126>The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
'The' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
you was unexpected at this time.
```

Is there any way to suppress all output from Ant, or at least get Capistrano not to pass any output from my build script to the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on both [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/134214/dev-null-for-windows) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe).

```
set :build_script, "ant compress -q > NUL"
```