# Delete a directory and its files using command line but don't throw error if it doesn't exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a Windows command to delete a directory and all its containing files but I do not want to see any errors if the directory does not exist.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Redirect the output of the `del` command to nul. Note the `2`, to indicate error output should be redirected. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe), and especially the tech doc [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

```
del {whateveroptions} 2>null
```

Or you can check for file existence before calling `del`:

```
if exist c:\folder\file del c:\folder\file
```

Note that you can use `if exist c:\folder\` (with the trailing `\`)  to check if `c:\folder` is indeed a folder and not a file.

Comment: Tried this i still get "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Force recursive deletion, ignore errors: `rmdir /s /q some\where\myFolder 2>nul`

Comment: @crusy Much appreciated, but that is the same answer (`rmdir` = `rd`) that dbenham already gave  exactly _6 years_ ago

Answer (score 76):

Either redirect stderr to nul

```
rd /q /s "c:\yourFolder" 2>nul
```

Or verify that folder exists before deleting. Note that the trailing `\` is critical in the IF condition.

```
if exist "c:\yourFolder\" rd /q /s "c:\yourFolder"
```

Comment: @GolezTrol - Neither of you deleted the folder as requested by the OP. Both of you focused on deleting a file.

Answer (score 42):

For me on Windows 10 the following is working great:

```
if exist <path> rmdir <path> /q /s
```

`q` stands for "delete without asking" and `s` stands for "delete all subfolders and files in it".

And you can also concatinate the command:

```
(if exist <path> rmdir <path> /q /s) && <some other command that executes after deleting>
```

Comment: Concatinate helps me, otherwise it wont to work when `rmdir` paired with `if exist`.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect stderr to nul

```
del filethatdoesntexist.txt 2>nul
```

Comment: Did you try this?  This doesn't work.  If it doesn't exist, I still see the error

Answer (score 1):

The above comes up with Y or N in the prompt. So, I used the following instead and it works perfectly.

```
if exist cddd rmdir cddd
```

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers.

Comment: To avoid the prompt you have to add __/Q__ to the rmdir command. If you need to remove all files and subdirectories you need also __/S__. You didn't see the prompt probably because the directory was not there.