# Makefile Windows -- remove directory if exists

Tags: if-statement, makefile, directory, exists, rmdir

I am trying to port a Makefile to Windows (using GNU Make). I am having trouble with removing directories. I found this question ([Delete a directory and its files using command line but don't throw error if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502612/delete-a-directory-and-its-files-using-command-line-but-dont-throw-error-if-it-d)) on how to conditionally remove directories, but I get an error trying to use that solution, translating approximately to `The use of ""doc\html"" is syntactically impermissible in this context`

The snippet causing it is this:

`if exists "doc\html\" rmdir /Q /S doc\html`

I also tried

`cmd /c if exists "doc\html" cmd /c rmdir /Q /S doc\html`

and

`cmd /c if exists "doc\html\" cmd /c rmdir /Q /S doc\html`.

I also tried `rmdir /Q /S doc\html 2>nul`. That works kind of. The error gets redirected, but Make still throws an error and stops.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the command is `exist` not `exists`. There is a typo in the thread I linked...