# GNU Make: "pipe: No such file or directory" error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a Makefile that works on both Windows and Linux. Running `make clean`  generates the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rmdir /s /q D:\Documents\Programming\project\bin, ...) failed.
make: Makefile:13: pipe: No such file or directory
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rmdir /s /q D:\Documents\Programming\project\obj, ...) failed.
make: Makefile:15: pipe: No such file or directory
```

The relevant parts of the Makefile are:

```
BIN_DIR=bin
OBJ_DIR=obj
SRC_DIR=src

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    RMDIR=$(shell rmdir /s /q $(subst /,\,$(abspath $1)))
else
    RMDIR=$(shell rm -rf $(abspath $1))
endif

clean:
    @echo "RM $(BIN_DIR)"
    @$(call RMDIR,$(BIN_DIR))
    @echo "RM $(OBJ_DIR)"
    @$(call RMDIR,$(OBJ_DIR))
    @echo "Done!"

.PHONY: clean
```

The project structure looks like this:

```
├─bin
├─obj
├─src
└─Makefile
```

Comment: I am not familiar with how windows behaves if you try to remove a directory that does not exists, in linux, on the other hand, by adding `-f` basically you are silencing the diagnostic. Perhaps it is worth to try something like what is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502670/4868875

Comment: This should not happen on a recent version of make. Please show your `make --version` output for Windows `make`.

Comment: First, please remove all the `@` in your recipes, then show the output make prints.  Adding `@` when your makefile doesn't work is like trying to debug your problem blindfolded.  Second, why are you using `$(shell ...)` here from inside a recipe?  That's almost always wrong.  Why not just say `RMDIR = rmdir /s ...` without the `$(shell ...)`?