# ReadKey InvalidOperationException application does not have a console

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to use `ReadKey()` to get a password field so it doesn't show in the console for a .net core app I am running on Ubuntu.

This is code:

```cs
while (true)
{
    var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);

    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        break;

    Io.RootPass += key.KeyChar;
}
```

But I get this exception:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Console.dll: 'Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.'

`Console.ReadLine()` doesn't work either it just doesn't throw an exception. The return value is not assigned when enter hit so the program sticks.

I am guessing this is because Linux terminal works differently. Is there a different interface for Linux terminal that works?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939666/c-sharp-readkey-crashing-console-app-when-called-using-nul

Comment: @EvanTrimboli my code is the same as in the answer of the one you link me to

Comment: I think issue is because im running in Ubuntu terminal

Comment: For whatever its worth I wasn't able to reproduce your error under Ubuntu 14.04 with .net-core 2.0.2., I used the same code except for what I did with the read in keys.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Found my answer in OmniSharp Visual Code docs: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window

> Console (terminal) window
>
> By default, processes are launched with their console output
>   (stdout/stderr) going to the VS Code Debugger Console. This is useful
>   for executables that take their input from the network, files, etc.
>   But this does NOT work for applications that want to read from the
>   console (ex: Console.ReadLine). For these applications, use a setting
>   such as the following:
>
> "console": "integratedTerminal" When this is set to integratedTerminal
>   the target process will run inside VS Code's integrated terminal.
>   Click the 'Terminal' tab in the tab group beneath the editor to
>   interact with your application.
>
> When this is set to externalTerminal the target process will run in a
>   separate terminal.

I changed this setting in launch.json and now it works

Comment: I have no launch.json file, where is this located?

Comment: Its created by vscode when you click debug settings.

Comment: Could you please check that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300317/how-to-create-a-navigation-menu-in-dotnet-application

Comment: I just went back and checked my code to see what I did as this was over a year ago.  Looks like I refactored app to work from command line arguments and settings file

Comment: could you show me the way in my question? I'll be grateful

Comment: For anyone interested, an external terminal can also debug, which works better and less clunky than the VS Code integrated terminal : `"console": "externalTerminal"`

Comment: I faced the same InvalidOperationException while running a standard C# application in VS Code. As per my observation, the launch.json file containing the "console" property is created only for .Net 5+ and .Net Core applications from debug settings. The launch.json file that's created for standard C# applications neither contains nor supports the "console" property. Does it affect a standard C# application in any way? If yes, then how to get around it? Please explain.

Comment: I've asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77854353/how-to-configure-json-options-for-c-sharp-dotnet-to-debug-console-app-in-intern/77854391)  about problem which @priyamtheone mentions. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I deployed my webjob to Azure, and received similar error.
I fixed the issue by following check;

```
if (!Console.IsInputRedirected && Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    string read = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();

                    if (read == "f")
                    { // run your logic ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Something that I have used in my own code (which as far as I can see is not mentioned in the linked question) is `Console.In` which interacts directly with the standard input.
I have tested it in my own project with both Windows CMD and openSUSE KTerm and it works as expected.

My code is specifically:
`Console.In.ReadLineAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
because it's in the IO handling BackgroundWorker which is running Async.
Yours may be able to get away with `Console.In.ReadKey();`, though YMMV as I've not tested anything except `ReadLine`.

Comment: so essentially what is the solution?

Comment: Essentially the solution would be ```Console.In.Readkey();``` instead of ```System.Console.ReadKey()``` because in the off chance that console input was redirected, `Console.In` would access it where `Console` by itself may not.