# When running a c# code in vs code, i doesn't open the console

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The code is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");Console.ReadKey();
```

And it gives me this error:

> Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read

Comment: what kind of application are you building? does it have a visual ui?

Comment: why do you want to use Console.ReadKey();? use Console.Read() or Console.ReadLine();
  instead .

Comment: What's your project template? Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901071/readkey-not-working-in-net-core) help you

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT it actually solved my problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new Project in Visual Studio, make sure to select a Console Application Type as your Project Template.

It is possible to change the Project Type after creating a Project through the Project Properties, but since it looks like you are starting from scratch, you might want to restart with a new project template.

Comment: I havent opened a new project, I opened a folder, then created a new terminal and typed `dotnet new console` . Have i done something wrong?

Comment: Interesting, that should work. Which platform are you running on?

Comment: Maybe check the outputType in the csproj File, it should be Exe for Console Apps in .NET Core. You can also try to add: <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference> if it keeps changing to WinExe

Answer (score 0):

We can found answer in OmniSharp Visual Code docs: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window

[image]

You can also refer to this page: [ReadKey not working in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901071/readkey-not-working-in-net-core)