# how to configure .json options for C# to debug console app in internal terminal in VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Actually, the problem I'm having right now is exactly same as [ReadKey InvalidOperationException application does not have a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901071/readkey-invalidoperationexception-application-does-not-have-a-console).

But the all provided solutions in that question don't work for me. The reason they don't work is I can neither add `"console": "integratedTerminal"` nor `"internalConsole":true` (These options available in [VS Code official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings#_console-terminal-window) as well). But I've searched a lot but there is nothing about these.

VS Code warns as "property console/internalConsole isn't allowed."

[image: Error message for not allowed property in json file vs code]

My current .json configuration file is as following:

```json
        {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
            "name": "C#: Events Example",
            "type": "dotnet",
            "request": "launch",
            "projectPath": "${workspaceFolder}/Event/Event.csproj",
            "launchConfigurationId": "TargetFramework=;Microsoft.NETCore.App"
            }
        ]
        }
```

As a summary, how can I use terminal to debug C# app in VS Code in Linux?

Comment: Try using `"type": "coreclr"` instead of `"dotnet"`. That one should support the `console` and `internalConsole` properties. Also, instead of pointing at your `.csproj`, you point it at the output `.dll` [Here's an example](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/.vscode/launch.json)

Comment: @NPras, Yes, it worked! You can post the answer. I'll accept it. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSCode C# Extension brings in with it a configuration `"type": "coreclr"`. This in turn brings the `console` property needed to tell VSCode where to redirect `stdin/out`.

We also need to point to the produced `.dll` instead of the `.csproj`. The config will look something like the following:

```
  "name": "Launch Me",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
  "console": "integratedTerminal" //or internalConsole, or externalTerminal
```

The complete documentation is [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings#_console-terminal-window). An example of a functional `launch.json` for C# can be seen [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/.vscode/launch.json).