# Silencing TYPE Output in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to suppress the console output in Windows when I execute the TYPE command, e.g.:

> TYPE myfile.dat.* > myfile.dat

The console keeps returning the list of file that were read. Since I am already redirecting the output to a file, I cannot use the > NUL redirection. Any ideas on this? Thank you!

Comment: Use `2>NUL` to suppress diagnostic output.

Comment: Great, that solved it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect stderr to null in cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe)