# Redirection to 'NUL' failed: FileStream will not open Win32 devices

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, appveyor

I am trying to remove some verbosity from a `choco install` command within AppVeyor. Here is what I been trying (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4507627/136285)):

```
if (Test-Path "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/swig.exe") {
    echo "using swig from cache"
} else {
    choco install swig > NUL
}
```

However it fails with:

```
Redirection to 'NUL' failed: FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as
disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\\.\" in the path.
At line:4 char:5
+     choco install swig > NUL
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionFailed

Command executed with exception: Redirection to 'NUL' failed: FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\\.\" in the path.
```

So my question is there a way to suppress the verbosity of a `choco install` command within PowerShell on AppVeyor?

Comment: `choco install swig > $null`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Comment: Throwing this out there - you should add `-y` to the argument as it may fail to finish installing depending on the version of choco.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nul` is batch syntax. In PowerShell you can use `$null` instead, as Mathias R. Jessen pointed out in his comment:

```
choco install swig > $null
```

Other options are piping into the `Out-Null` cmdlet, collecting the output in a variable, or casting it to `void`:

```
choco install swig | Out-Null
$dummy = choco install swig
[void](choco install swig)
```

Comment: It is not specific to the shell. It is a valid native Win32 filename for the `NUL` device. But most of .NET does not allow them.